# launch lisp REPL error

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying one of the first [CRAM tutorial](http://cram-system.org/doc/beginner/package_for_turtlesim) and it says 'launch lisp REPL.'
I have installed roslisp but when i run 'rosrun roslisp_repl repl' as the [roslisp tutorial](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/roslisp%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29BasicUsage.html) says to do, I get *"[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named repl below /opt/ros/groovy/share/roslisp_repl"*

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Btw, I am using Ros Groovy on ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190066/launch-lisp-repl-error/) by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-14**:
Does that directory exist? What files does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You were using an old version of the roslisp tutorial, I suggest to always refer to the original wiki.rog.org pages instead of mirrors. If you installed roslisp_repl from source then the command would be

```
$ rosrun roslisp_repl roslisp_repl
```

otherwise it's simply

```
$ roslisp_repl
```

You can find the original tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/BasicUsage)

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-01-12**:
Note: I guess it's too late to answer this question now (my email subscription filter didn't work as expected so I missed this, sorry) but as I didn't find any guidelines on how old a question should be not to revive it, I'm putting an answer here in any case for future reference.